# Hide/Show Column in rich Datatable on Client Side

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I have a Rich:Datatable with 10+ columns. I want to hide/show some columns based on user action. But wanted to it client side. I know we can do it taking the action to the server and re-rendering the datatable. But wanted to do it on client side.

Working on Richfaces 4.5.

```
<rich:dataTable binding="#{tblBind}" id="tblBindId" value="#{exampleController.tableValues}" var="tableVal">

<rich:column>
 <f:facet name="header">
 <h:outputText value="Field 1" />
 </f:facet>
  <h:outputText id="fieldOneId" value="#{tableVal.fieldOne}" style="width:135px;color:black;">
<f:attribute name="rowid" value="#{tblBind.rowIndex}" />
 </h:outputText>
</rich:column>

<rich:column>
 <f:facet name="header">
 <h:outputText value="Field 2" />
 </f:facet>
  <h:outputText id="fieldTwoId" value="#{tableVal.fieldTwo}" style="width:135px;color:black;">
<f:attribute name="rowid" value="#{tblBind.rowIndex}" />
 </h:outputText>
</rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
</fieldset>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the **generated html client-side**. Then use javascript to hide the things you want to hide... Most likely it's all tables or divs. Nothing JSF or RichFaces related...

Comment: `rich:extendedDataTable` comes with this functionality, any reason you can't use it?

Comment: @Kukeltje, as you seem to be so smart, you could provide the suggestion about which "things" to hide and how. Rich:column are translated to table columns; it's not that straightforward.

Comment: @Pere: Not without seeing the generated html. And since this project is old, it is impossible for me to try to get an example working, sorry